# Can you pass functions between components in React-Native (in different files)?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a class in which I have a method I want to call. Specifically the `() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')`. At first I was using a button attached to each FeedCard to navigate, but it looked sloppy so instead I decided upon touchable opacity.

HomeScreen.js

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
    state = { }
    render() {
        return(
            <Root>
                <List>
                    <FeedCard />
                    <FeedCard doThis={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')} />
                    <FeedCard />
                    <FeedCard />
                    <FeedCard />
                    <FeedCard />
                    <FeedCard />
                </List>
            </Root>
        )
    }
};
```

Is it possible to pass functions (similar to what I did using `doThis()` in react native?

FeedCard.js

```
function FeedCard({doThis}) {
    return (
        <Root>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={doThis}>
                <FeedCardHeader />
                <CardContainer>
                    <CardContentText>
                        {text}
                    </CardContentText>
                </CardContainer>
                <FeedCardBottom />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Root>
    )
};
```

When I put the function directly into the `onPress()` for the `<TouchableOpacity>` component it returned `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props')`, so I wanted to know if it is at all possible to pass a function similar to the way I attempted above. But with the code above, it does not navigate at all. I know the navigation works because when I put it in an `onPress()` in a `<Button>` on the same page as the HomeScreen it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass blank function into other Feedcard

```js
<FeedCard doThis={() => { }} />
<FeedCard doThis={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')} />
<FeedCard doThis={() => { }} />
<FeedCard doThis={() => { }} />
<FeedCard doThis={() => { }} />
<FeedCard doThis={() => { }} />
<FeedCard doThis={() => { }} />
```

If you don't want to pass it. Do as below

```js
function FeedCard({doThis}) {
    return (
        <Root>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => ÏdoThis}>
                <FeedCardHeader />
                <CardContainer>
                    <CardContentText>
                        {text}
                    </CardContentText>
                </CardContainer>
                <FeedCardBottom />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Root>
    )
};
```